# Why is there a nullpointerException when execute the AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream?

Tags: java, java-11

I am sure that the file name is right! So what is the problem in `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream`?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    public static Clip clip;
    AudioInputStream audioStream = null;
    try {
        //URL soundUrl = Main.class.getResource("D:/eclipse/workplace/AudioTestAPI/2.mp3");
        URL soundUrl = Main.class.getResource("D:/eclipse/workplace/AudioTestAPI/3.wav");
        audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundUrl);//42
        clip.open(audioStream);
    } catch(LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException eo) {
        eo.printStackTrace();
    }

    clip.start();

    do {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while(clip.isActive());
}
```

}

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1032)
at Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

Comment: What is `clip`?

Comment: I have changed my fomat, you can see it now

Comment: How do you initialize your variable `clip`?

Comment: The argument to [getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) is **not** a file name.  It’s a resource path, which is a relative URL.  Passing a file name will always result in the resource not being found, which is why the method returns null.

Comment: So what the URL of a file should be in this case? Thank you@VGR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.lang.NullPointerException` occurs because your variable `soundUrl` is `null`.

Try this:

```
File file = new File("D:/eclipse/workplace/AudioTestAPI/3.wav");
audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
```

Let me know what happened after my suggestion.

Edited:

```
package com.acme.audio;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {

        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream audioStream = null;

        try {

            File file = new File("D:/eclipse/workplace/AudioTestAPI/3.wav");
            audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            clip.open(audioStream);

        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException eo) {
            eo.printStackTrace();
        }

        clip.start();

        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (clip.isActive());

    }

}
```

Comment: It does not work well, there is a new java.lang.NullPointerException happened in the line of "clip.open(audioStream);" I do not know how to solve that? Thank you, @João Zarate

Comment: @RedRabbit How do you initialize your variable clip?

Comment: just like the above class: "public static Clip clip;" I should set to null at first?

Comment: Even if I set to null, still the  java.lang.NullPointerException happened in the line of "clip.open(audioStream);"

Comment: Try it `Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();`

Comment: @RedRabbit I just edited this answer with my code example ... works here ... I can hear the song.